# Specify or omit table output r

Tags: r

I have a table command as follows:

```
table(wt.combined@meta.data[["expanded"]], wt.combined@active.ident,  wt.combined@meta.data[["orig.ident"]])
```

The last element of the table (wt.combined@meta.data[["orig.ident"]]) has two factors (wt.UT and wt.aCT), so the command makes two count tables. I'd like to know how to specify which factor so I only get one table.

Something like this (which doesn't work):

```
table(wt.combined@meta.data[["expanded"]], wt.combined@active.ident,  wt.combined@meta.data[["orig.ident"]] = "wt.UT")
```

or (as suggested in comments)

```
i<-wt.combined@meta.data[["orig.ident"]] == "wt.UT"
table(wt.combined@meta.data[["expanded"]], wt.combined@active.ident, wt.combined@meta.data[["orig.ident"]][i])
```

which produces this error:

```
Error in table(wt.combined@meta.data[["expanded"]], wt.combined@active.ident,  : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

Comment: `i<-wt.combined@meta.data[["orig.ident"]] == "wt.UT"` Then create the table with `wt.combined@meta.data[["orig.ident"]][i]`.

Comment: I've circumvented the issue by adding as.data.frame( to the start of the line, it doesn't separate the data, but puts it in a melted format suitable for separating downstream.